# C# Loading a file from a command line?

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd

I am relatively new to C# and I am having a little trouble.

I am creating a program where I want to load a file from the command line. For example:

```
MyProgram.exe C:\ExcelDocument.xls
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the `Main` method of your program the `args` string array parameter to the method will contain any command line parameters.  The args array will contain 1 value for each space separated element that is not enclosed in quotes (")

so

```
myprograme.exe c:\my documents\file1.xls
```

will result in 2 args:

```
c:\my
documents\file1.xls
```

whereas

```
myprograme.exe "c:\my documents\file1.xls"
```

will result in 1 value in args:

```
c:\my documents\file1.xls
```

you can access the params via the indexer:

```
string file = args[0];
```

assuming that the file is the first argument.

obviously you will still need to load the actual file, this will only give you the name give as a parameter to your program.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.  If this answers your question you should click the tick under the voting buttons to the left of the questions to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

you can retrieve the file by using args[0].

```
public static void Main(string [] args)
{
    //This will print the first argument you passed in on command line.
    Console.WriteLine(args[0]); 
}
```